Archive page for custom post type shows regular posts, too (by category)
I have a custom post type ("appointments") and a archive page for it ("archive-appointments.php") where I can see of course all the appointments. I have activated the standard categories for the appointments post type to keep it simple (they are used for posts, too). Problem: When I click on a category link on an appointment that is also used in a post, that post is shown on my appointments archive page, too. Any idea how to avoid that?

Without knowing the code this impossible to to look into

In the "archive-appointments.php" is a standard loop, that's all. In the "single-appointments" are category links like "my-website/category/banana/" which lead to the archive page "archive-appointments.php" where I only want to see the appointments, but because some news have the same category ("banana") they are shown on that page, too, event that archive page is for appointments ("archive-appointments.php").

do you have a pre_get_posts hook in your code? Note that the appointments post type archive is not the same thing as the category term archive, try to be very specific and include example URLs or you might be misunderstood

Because I don't have a term archive it uses the custom post type archive for the appointments. So you say I should make a template like "single-appointments-category" or something? The code in my template is just a standard loop "while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();"
